# Close QTcpSocket from another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, sockets, networking

I use a `QTcpSocket` in a dedicated thread. For close this thread, I have a personal slot connected with the `disconnected` signal of the `QTcpSocket`. This slot contains the `socket.close()` instruction.

```
class Network
{
   private:

      QTcpSocket *mp_Socket;

   public:

      void connection()
      {
         mp_Socket = new QTcpSocket(this);

         // Move to thread

         connect(mp_Socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(disconnect()));
      }

   public slots:

      void disconnect()
      {
         mp_Socket->close();
      }
};
```

Here, the slot works (even if the socket is in another thread).
But if I call the disconnect slot by myself, i have the following error :

> "QSocketNotifier: socket notifiers cannot be disabled from another thread".

Why?

Thanks for your help. ;)

Comment: Have you tried to emit a signal from the other thread?

Comment: Socket operations by members of the socket is closed.
Chained to an external data conditions.
Makes it difficult to back off pursuit operations.

Comment: I tried to emit a signal as QTcpSocket with disconnected signal but I have same error.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so you may need to change your design a little. Instead of moving only the socket to a new thread, make your `Network` class `Object` derived, and move it instead, and have the socket parented to it. My previous answer revision did not work because `close()` was not registered with the Qt meta system, because it is a plain virtual function, not a slot. With the new design you can have interthread signals and slots which will solve the problem. Connections between objects in different threads will automatically be resolved as queued and use the event loop to schedule execution in the correct thread.

Also, I notice you have a slot in your current class, without it being `QObject` derived. That will not work, you need Qt's meta system to have slots. You don't get an error, because `slots` compiles to nothing in C++, it is only used by the MOC (meta object compiler), so you don't really have a slot.

Naturally, this means that `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(yourNetworkClass, "disconnect", Qt::QueuedConnection)` will now also work.

Comment: "QMetaObject::invokeMethod: No such method QTcpSocket::close()" Is it normal ?

Comment: @Maluna34 - seems like `close()` is not registered with the meta system. Are you using Qt version 5 or newer?

Comment: I'm using version 5.4.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this.

Comment: Is the QTcpSocket destructor closing the connection ? If the socket is parented to the Network class, the destruction will close the connection and so, send the disconnected signal to the peer ?

Comment: I tried to put the Network class in the thread and I'm able to close it with invokeMethod. But other part of the network application don't work anymore. But with your solution, I learnt that I have to use deleteLater instead of delete. So, if I run deleteLater on the socket, it should be closed too.

Comment: Use deleteLater instead of close solves the original error. ;)